# How can bitfinex send LTC to a Bitcoin address?

Tags: litecoin, p2sh, cross-chain-recovery, address-format

[image]

It's my fault.

However, how come bitfinex doesn't guard against this error?

Also how can it be possible?

`32uxxMqwrpEKTDodF8BZkuRJGs8ruujoti` is clearly not an LTC address. I am not even sure how the LTC network handles this.

The money is most likely gone. I am just pissed and wonder how it's possible?

In binance I would at least got a warning. We give an address and their system will tell us what chains the address supports.

Answer (score 1):

Litecoin used the same address format for P2SH before introducing their "M…" format. [image]

The underlying script that is encoded in the address is still equivalent for either the ["3…" or the "M…" prefix](https://www.ellipal.com/pages/ltc-convert-m-address-to-3-address-p2sh-converter). If you control the Bitcoin address, you may be able to import the corresponding key from your Bitcoin wallet to your Litecoin to spend your funds.

If you are looking for pointers how to do that, you might want to peruse topics in our [cross-chain-recovery](/questions/tagged/cross-chain-recovery) tag.